# Tables embedded in DIV's

Tags: html, css

Okay guys I have a question about positioning tables within DIV's using CSS.

I have code as follows:

css:

```
#content{
    float:right;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:450px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:left;
}

#content .reviewTable{
    width:20px;
}
#news{
    line-height: 18px;
    width:150px;
}


#news h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#news p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right:10px;
    font-size:13px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="reviewTable">
    <table>
    <td></td>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

My table sits far away from my news DIV there is some padding around the news DIV however I have removed that and it didn't make any difference to the positioning of the table. I have been looking at other Stack Overflow posts but can't seem to find what I am looking for. I have tried absolute and relative positioning in my CSS and also width and none of these work not the table where they have worked on other elements such as plain text.

I have also tried the table as `<table class="reviewTable"></table>`

My question is does the code need to be in a certain format in order to allow the positioning of tables in a DIV which already has CSS formatting applied to it?

Just looking for a hint in the right direction guys if you could help me out or anyone else has a similar problem as this it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing some closing `>` - is that a typo in your post or in your code?  Your `<tr>` is absent too.

Comment: would be best if you setup an example on http://jsfiddle.net to see what you are talking about

Comment: I set up a starter jsfiddle, but it needs more of the page elements added: http://jsfiddle.net/D45Z5/

Comment: @NATHANC One thing that shouldn't be a big deal is your are including your CSS twice

Comment: Sorry but can you clarify please where I am including it twice?

Comment: @NATHANC when I view the source there are 2 `@import "css/master.css";` of these

Comment: Apologies I see what you mean about adding my stylesheet twice. But I am not sure if that is causing my problems.

Comment: I removed that line of code and the page doesn't work, so i put it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your table is flowing outside is that you are floating it right.  Then you have the width set to be too small for the review area so it makes it go outside.  Change the width of the `#content` to `600px` and you'll see what I mean.

For the way you have it setup you need to set the `#content` to `610px`.  Set the `#page-container` to `overflow:hidden` to prevent anything showing if its outside your container.  And take off the width on `.reviewTable`

Comment: Brilliant! Thats just what I was looking for. So basically the table wouldn't fit within the content Div so it positioned it outside it? It didn't look like it was positioned outside it thats why I was confused :S

Comment: The reason I was trying to embed it in another DIV was because I have some text on my main page which uses #content div. So I was just wondering is it possible to override the smaller DIV by putting a larger DIV inside it for the table to expand?

Comment: @NATHANC The div wasn't really positioned outside of your container but rather spilling over.  By floating and having the width too small the content spills outside of the container.

Comment: @NATHANC as for your other question not sure really what you mean.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a larger width DIV inside a smaller DIV? Is there no way of overriding it?

Comment: @NATHANC check out this http://jsfiddle.net/Y44Ex/1/ .  Essentially whats happens is that an outer `div` will expand horizontally `100%` by default unless the container its in stops it nothing inside of it will ever make it bigger.  Height on the other hand will shrink to contain just the content and expand to contain the contents unless you `float` or `absolute` position something.

Comment: I have check the tick next to your answer it won't allow me to vote until I have 15 reputation though. Is there anything else you need me to do?